# Install dependencies dynamically for pytest/unittest suite

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, subprocess, pytest, python-unittest

I have a `tests/` dir with `test_1.py`, `test_2.py` , `test_3.py`. Test 2 and 3 requires an external dependency that can be compiled with a CLI command eg. `build dep_a`. Test 3 requires an additional dependency `dep_b`

I want to run `build dep_a` when only test 2 is run. And whenever test_2 and test_3 run `build dep_a dep_b`. I also don't want to run this if only test_1 is run, since it doesnt need either. Each dependency should only be built once for each `pytest` run.

Ideally, each test file can have a `TEST_DEPS = ["dep_a","dep_b", ...]` at the top.

I tried calling `subprocess.run(<build command>)` on each file, but that will re-build all the dependencies even if they have already been built, even in the same run.

I also tried a pre-run set up to build all dependencies, but it will build all even if we run a single test that does not need any dependencies.